Vite PWA - Precached routes and development mode
using vite-pwa on a vue application.
Production mode
When building my app for production using yarn build a sw.js file is generated along with my bundle. This file contains precacheAndRoute, an array containing all the assests precached
Example
{ url: "index.html", revision: "b96296b430fbbc907a9494c48467c1c0" },
{ url: "LOCAL/AccountSettings.8227aa0d.js", revision: null },
{ url: "LOCAL/AddRemoveTeamMembersMassActionCreate.767d3131.js", revision: null }

This works well as all my assets are pre-cached right away
Development mode
When using yarn dev a dev-dist the sw.js file contains
e.precacheAndRoute(
            [
                { url: "registerSW.js", revision: "3ca0b8505b4bec776b69afdba2768812" },
                { url: "index.html", revision: "0.jiej681smt" },
            ],
            {}
        ),

Which means as far as I tried and understand that not all my assets are pre-cached.
Question
Is there a way to reproduce the same behavior in production and development mode?
Vite config
VitePWA({
        registerType: 'autoUpdate',
        injectRegister: 'auto',
        devOptions: {
          enabled: true, // Enable PWA in development mode
          type: 'module', // Use ES module-based service worker (for modern browsers)
        },
        workbox: {
          maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000,
        },
      }),

